# Writing Byte Array to File On Android Not Working

Tags: java, android, file, io, byte

I am trying to save the byte stream I receive from a device to an h264 file on Android. I set the bytebuffer to be 30 MB. The strange thing is that when I view the content of the saved file using an Hex editor, only around 4 MB of the data at the beginning seems to be reasonable. All the rest of the data is 0x00. This is out of my expectation and I am using Nexus 6p for testing.

My code snippet. Basically I receive the data from a callback and I save it to the byte buffer each time. When I get 2500 such byte arrays, I save them altogether to a file.

```
private ByteBuffer stream_data = ByteBuffer.allocate(30000000);
...

//Callback function
public void onResult(byte[] videoBuffer, int size){
            mDjiGLSurfaceView.setDataToDecoder(videoBuffer, size);
            if (count1 <= 2500) {
                if (size > 6) {
                    stream_data.put(Arrays.copyOfRange(videoBuffer, 0, size));
                    count1++;
                }
            }
            else if (count1 == 2501){
                count1++;
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        try{
                            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DJI_Data");
                            if (!root.exists()) {
                                root.mkdirs();
                            }
                            File hola = new File(root, "stream_2500.h264");

                            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(hola));
                            bos.write(stream_data.array());
                            bos.flush();
                            bos.close();

                            handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(SHOWTOAST, "File Saved!"));

                            stream_data.clear();
                            stream_data.rewind();
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why are you declaring a byte buffer? And then one of 30MB? Do away with it and write the bytes of videoBuffer directly to file.

Comment: That was because my other parts of the code need this bytebuffer. But yeah thanks for your suggestion and I will try directly writing the byte array to the file.